# How do you decorate your home in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

I found a padlock and chain in the desert.  It claims to be a home decoration.  In my home, I don't seem to have the option of decorating with it.

Is it because my home is a tent?  Or because I have no AP so it's not listing the option?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply placing decorative objects in your home is enough, there's nothing else you need to do. You'll gain the effect of the item as long as it remains there.

The padlock you found prevents other people from stealing from you when you're out of town. Other items may provide decoration points which are granted to your soul when you die.

Comment: Padlocks are such killjoys.  My first order of business was to kife my neighbour's washing machine.